# play a video with vlc and then cleanly terminate the process

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm writing a script that plays video and audio files with different players. In this wise, vlc is not unique and I'd like to avoid using any specific options like "--play-and-exit". The problem with vlc/cvlc is that after playing a video/audio (from terminal) it doesn't terminate the process.
The best what I can do can be illustrated by the following script that only works in ipython:

```
import subprocess


def play_with_vlc():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/vlc', PATH_TO_FILE])
    try:
        subprocess.communicate(timeout=5)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        proc.kill()
        proc.communicate()


play_with_vlc()
```

However it's not the solution that I'm looking for. Because I'm not supposed to know how long it takes to play a video. I just want to cleanly and safely terminate the vlc process after it stops playing a file. But it should not be something specific.
Is there any way to do this?

**EDIT:**

Okay, from what I've learnt so far I'm forced to conclude that the best way to go would be to calculate the duration of the files. 
It could be done by subprocessing  the `$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 PATH` linux command.

But what I still don't quite understand is why the following script doesn't work as expected.

```
import subprocess
import sys


def play_with_vlc(path_to_file=sys.argv[1]):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/vlc', path_to_file])
    try:
        subprocess.communicate(timeout=5)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        proc.kill()
        proc.communicate()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    play_with_vlc()
```

Comment: A general solution without knowing the length of the video? No, there isn't one.

Comment: If you don't know how long the video is, then find out. That's the easiest solution that works with any video player.

Comment: @stybl So what you're saying is that it's impossible to know if the video stopped playing?

Comment: @Foobard It might be, but only for a specific video player. There isn't such a solution that would work for *any* player.

Comment: @Rawing well, it can be used as the last resort. I know.

Comment: @Rawing Okay, I will go with this option. But why does this function only work in ipython?